# How to combine different ffmpeg commands

Tags: android, audio, video, ffmpeg

I'm using `ffmpeg` in Android to first add a sound track to a video, then add a watermark on top of it. I'm currently using 2 different commands, which means that both processes are completely independent (once the video with the audio is generated, I run the command to add a watermark on top of it).

These are the commands I'm using:

Add audio: `ffmpeg -i video -i audio -vcodec copy -shortest output_vid`

Add watermark: `ffmpeg -i output_vid -i watermark -filter_complex overlay=10:10 final_vid`

Is there a way to combine these 2 commands and run them in a single pass over the original video? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i video -i watermark -i audio -filter_complex overlay=10:10 -shortest final_vid
```

This will likely fail if video has an existing audio track.